# Piped text for Webservice params in qualtrics

Tags: web-services, qualtrics

My requirement is to get the email ID from the user in qualtrics and to invoke a webservice with email as a param at the end of the registration . The webservice will register the user in my site. Actually i am not getting how to get the piped text code for the email field(I created as a question for email). Also i couldn't see the option of GET/POST in the qualtrics webservice. Can anyone please help me how to generate a piped text code for the email question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under web service parameters you would have:

```
email = ${pipedTextField}
```

Where pipedTextField would be something like q://QID1/ChoiceTextEntryValue if it was a text question.  An easy way to get the correct pipedTextField value is to create a temporary embedded data field and use the drop down to pick the piped text. Then copy that to your web service parameter field.

There is no GET/POST option.  All web service calls are GET.

P.S. If my answer to your previous question about Qualtrics web service calls was helpful, please accept it.

Comment: Thanks @T. Gibbons. I am new to Qualtrics and help from you is amazing. I was looking for a POST option. I will try to achieve my job with GET.

Comment: Also i am facing one more issue, I have configured the webservice call after the question block expecting it to be invoked after the end of the survey.Do we need to configure anything more for this job?

Comment: You want the webservice call to be just before your end of survey block or at the end of the survey flow if you don't have an end of survey block in the survey flow.  Anything after an end of survey block in the survey flow won't be executed.

Comment: Sorry @T.Gibbons , I didn't get your point. Actually i am putting the webservice after the survey question block.
It will be like questionblock->webservice. Actually after the end of the survey,it is not hitting my webservice url. Sorry for asking again.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you.  When the respondent takes the survey, they never see or know about the web service call...it's invisible.  What the respondent sees after the survey is either an end of survey message or they get redirected to a website.  It is totally independent of the web service.

Comment: Hi @T.Gibbson, actually my task is done. It worked. Webservice is getting called now. Thank you very much for your help.